# Remove all in a List does not seem to be working c#

Tags: c#

I have a fairly simple question. I have a list of strings each of different length, the problem is to out put strings based on the string length sorted by descending order.. i.e from the longest to the smallest.

Here is what I am trying and not sure where I am going wrong.

```
namespace SortList
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> strings = new List<string>() { "12345678", "1", "12", "123456789", "123", "1234", "12345", "123456", "654321" };
            PrintWordss(strings);
        }



    private static void PrintWords(List<string> words)
    {
        var sortedWords = words.OrderByDescending(word => word.Length).ToList();
        foreach (var word in sortedWords)
        {
            if (DoSomeLogic(word))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(word + " and its lenght is = " + word.Length);
                sortedWords.RemoveAll(w => w.Length == word.Length);
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool DoSomeLogic(string word)
    {
        // Some complicated logic here which is not relevant to the problem.
        // Assuming this returns true.
        return true;
    }

    }

}
```

The output I am getting is

```
123456789 and its lenght is = 9
12345678 and its lenght is = 8
123456 and its lenght is = 6
654321 and its lenght is = 6
12345 and its lenght is = 5
1234 and its lenght is = 4
123 and its lenght is = 3
12 and its lenght is = 2
1 and its lenght is = 1
```

But what I would like to see is

```
123456789 and its lenght is = 9
12345678 and its lenght is = 8
123456 and its lenght is = 6
12345 and its lenght is = 5
1234 and its lenght is = 4
123 and its lenght is = 3
12 and its lenght is = 2
1 and its lenght is = 1
```

I would like to see "654321" which of length 6 to be removed from the list.

How can accomplish this while looping through the list ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What criteria determines what should be excluded from the list?

Comment: Basically if there are strings in the list of the same length only one of them should be printed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to ordering by string length, you need to group by string length and then select the first item from each group. This eliminates the need to modify the collection you're iterating over.

Use this instead:

```
private static void PrintWordss(List<string> words)
{
    var sortedWords = words.OrderByDescending(word => word.Length)
                           .GroupBy(word => word.Length)
                           .Select(word => word.First())
                           .ToList();

    foreach (var word in sortedWords)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} and its length is = {1}", word, word.Length);
}
```

Since the `OrderByDescending` places "123456" before "654321", this will drop "654321" from the results before assigning to `SortedWords`.

Tested with your data and got the desired output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Grant. But I have just simplified the logic that I want to accomplish. Let me try and explain, each string in the list is subjected a set of certain rules and conditions, once the rules are satisfied then the string needs to be removed from the list as well as all the strings which have the same length. So that the program picks up a string which is shorter than the one that was removed.  Is there way I can accomplish this using the foreach statement ?

Answer (score 0):

You're enumerating over `sortedWords.ToList()`, which is similar to saying:

```
var newList = sortedWords.ToList();
foreach(var newString in newList)
{
    // ...
}
```

When you remove from the original (`sortedWords`) list, the new list still contains all of the elements. A quick fix would be to change your enumeration to loop over sortedWords itself, unfortunately this means that you'll be changing your enumeration while enumerating, which is not allowed in C#.

A cleaner way may be to create a grouping, and only print one of the members of the group:

```
foreach (var group in sortedWords.GroupBy(x => x.Length))
{
    foreach(var word in group)
    {        
        if(SatisfiesRulesAndConditions(word))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word  + " and its length is = " + word.Length);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do that I get the following exception "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute"

Comment: Thanks for the reply NominSim. But I have just simplified the logic that I want to accomplish. Let me try and explain, each string in the list is subjected a set of certain rules and conditions, once the rules are satisfied then the string needs to be removed from the list as well as all the strings which have the same length. So that the program picks up a string which is shorter than the one that was removed.  Is there way I can accomplish this using the foreach statement ?

Comment: @user3375390 Edited to reflect the need to check each word within the group.

Comment: NominSim, I just updated the original issue. Thanks for your response but like I said I would not like to group list of strings by length even before calling the method  DoSomeLogic(string word) as inidicated in the question (which I edited recently). Is there anyway I can accomplish this while looping through the list ?

Comment: @user3375390 This code should still work to perform the same logic that you stated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting by the length, then grouping them together will let you grab just the distinct (via `FirstOfDefault`) lengths. The next thing you can do is then remove them from the source collection and not the collection you are iterating over. If you can't access the original (or don't want to), then create a locally scoped collection that contains the items and remove them from there.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> strings = new List<string>() { "12345678", "1", "12", "123456789", "123", "1234", "12345", "123456", "654321" };
    PrintWordss(strings);
    Console.WriteLine(strings.Count + " strings remain.");
}

private static bool SatisfiesRulesAndConditions(string word)
{
    return true;
}

private static void PrintWordss(List<string> words)
{
    var sortedWords = words.OrderByDescending(word => word.Length)
                               .GroupBy(word => word.Length)
                               .Select(word => word.First())
                               .ToList();

    foreach (var word in sortedWords)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(word + " and its lenght is = " + word.Length);

        if (SatisfiesRulesAndConditions(word))
        {
            words.RemoveAll(w => w.Length == word.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this is as follows:

```
123456789 and its lenght is = 9
12345678 and its lenght is = 8
123456 and its lenght is = 6
12345 and its lenght is = 5
1234 and its lenght is = 4
123 and its lenght is = 3
12 and its lenght is = 2
1 and its lenght is = 1
0 strings remain.
```

Since my `SatisfiesRulesAndConditions` method always returns true, at the very end of the loop, there will be zero items left in the collection. Note that since `List<string> words` is a reference to the original `List<string> strings` collection, removing them from the `words` parameter will remove them from the original collection as well. If you do not want this, then create a locally scoped field that can hold a copy of them for you like this.

```
private static void PrintWordss(List<string> words)
{
    var sortedWords = words.OrderByDescending(word => word.Length)
                               .GroupBy(word => word.Length)
                               .Select(word => word.First())
                               .ToList();

    // Clone list so original isn't modified.
    var copyofWords = words.Select(item => (string)item.Clone()).ToList();

    foreach (var word in sortedWords)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(word + " and its lenght is = " + word.Length);

        if (SatisfiesRulesAndConditions(word))
        {
            copyofWords.RemoveAll(w => w.Length == word.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this is as follows:

```
123456789 and its lenght is = 9
12345678 and its lenght is = 8
123456 and its lenght is = 6
12345 and its lenght is = 5
1234 and its lenght is = 4
123 and its lenght is = 3
12 and its lenght is = 2
1 and its lenght is = 1
9 strings remain.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wish those that down voted on an answer would explain why so the poster can learn something.

Comment: Not sure why it was dv. Seems like a good answer. Personally, I'm not exactly sure what the OP is looking for, or whether any of our answers are what he wants.